# Find host activity of FragmentActivity

Tags: android, parent, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Android class that extends a FragmentActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private double markerLat;
private double markerLon;
double[] toMark;
public final String LOG_TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
ActionBar actionBarFragment;
mapPositionListener mapMarker;

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    Activity hostActivity = getParent();
    try {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ERROR in try: " + fragment.getActivity().toString() + " ACTIVITY object " + hostActivity);
        mapMarker = (mapPositionListener) hostActivity;
    }
    catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ERROR post catch: " + fragment.getActivity().toString() + " must implement mapPositionListener");
        throw new ClassCastException(fragment.getActivity().toString() + " must implement mapPositionListener");
    }
}
```

My current code return a Null object.  How can I get the parent activity?
My searches found lots of examples for the Fragment but none for the FragmentActivity class.

Comment: Isn't getActivity() good enough for you to get the host activity?

Comment: "Activity hostActivity = getActivity()" or "Activity hostActivity = (name of my host class)getActivity()" result in Android Studio error msg "Cannot resolve 'getActivity()' method.